# Всплывающий текст при наведении курсора на элемент

Tags: html, css

Есть элемент  и задача такова, что при наведении курсора на элемент, должен всплывать элемент с текстом (хоть `div`, хоть `span` — это уже неважно, какой сделать).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать? `:hover` не работает.

Comment: jquery tooltip или bootstrap popover тебе  в помощь

Comment: Тебе нужен бутстрап фреймворк для таких целей.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

К любому html-элементу может быть применён атрибут title, текст которого будет показываться во всплывающей подсказке браузером.

```html
<p title="Этот текст будет показан при наведении">Просто текст</p>
```

---

Другой вариант на `:hover` отображать `::before` или `::after` с нужным контентом и соответствующей стилизацией. Обычно один из них используется для полезного контента, а второй для формирования треугольной стрелочки.

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Вы очень помогли.